# Some properties of finitely generated ideals in an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain.
Now suppose every finitely generated ideal of $R$ is principal; I conjecture that for any $a, b \in R$, at least one of them is invertible.

Is this a valid conjecture ? If yes, how do I make use of the principality property?

The reason behind the conjecture is that I have been tasked to show that the principality property stated can in fact be used as a definition for valuation ring.

Any help or insights is appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Your "conjecture" is wrong. Are 2 or 3 invertible in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: As stated, your conjecture is just a weird definition of a field... also, the principality property you're talking about (f.g. ideals being principal) is not equivalent to being a valuation domain.  It IS equivalent if the ring is additionally assumed local, but you haven't mentioned that.